Cannot overwrite the EIP register
Context
I am creating an application vulnerable to Buffer Overflow in Linux to practice this type of vulnerability (creation and exploitation) and I got stuck in this part.
My problem
I cannot overwrite the EIP register despite entering a bunch of "A" letters (around 1000), also, the program do not crashes when exceeding that buffer limit.
The purpose of this code is to enter a verification code (not vulnerable field), and then, requesting the "user" an email (no validation... this is the vulnerable field).
Objective
Be able to exploit a Buffer Overflow on the above code, modifying the less as possible its way to validate a "valid" user (first the valid code and then the email).
Code
Source Code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 6000
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256
#define CODE "xxxxxxxxxxx"

void handle_client(int client_socket) {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char email[64];

    send(client_socket, "Ingrese el código: ", 19, 0);
    recv(client_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

    if (strncmp(buffer, CODE, strlen(CODE)) == 0) {
        send(client_socket, "Código correcto. Ingrese su correo: ", 36, 0);
        recv(client_socket, email, 256, 0);
    scanf("%s", email);
        printf("Correo recibido: %s\n", email);
    } else {
        send(client_socket, "Código incorrecto.\n", 19, 0);
    }

    close(client_socket);
}

int main() {
    int server_socket, client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;

    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket < 0) {
        perror("Error al crear el socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error al enlazar el socket");
        close(server_socket);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(server_socket, 5) < 0) {
        perror("Error al escuchar en el socket");
        close(server_socket);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Servidor escuchando en el puerto %d\n", PORT);

    while (1) {
        addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
        client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addr_size);
        if (client_socket < 0) {
            perror("Error al aceptar la conexión");
            continue;
        }
        printf("Conexión recibida de %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
        handle_client(client_socket);
    }

    close(server_socket);
    return 0;
}

Compilation command
gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector source.c -o server -z execstack

Actual behavior
Right now I'm debugging it with GDB, and this is the output of the registers when inserting the payload:
gdb-peda$ info registers
eax            0x100               0x100
ecx            0xffffcd20          0xffffcd20
edx            0x100               0x100
ebx            0x4                 0x4
esp            0xffffccb8          0xffffccb8
ebp            0x0                 0x0
esi            0x0                 0x0
edi            0x0                 0x0
eip            0xf7fc657b          0xf7fc657b <__kernel_vsyscall+11>
eflags         0x246               [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x23                0x23
ss             0x2b                0x2b
ds             0x2b                0x2b
es             0x2b                0x2b
fs             0x0                 0x0
gs             0x63                0x63

As I understand the EIP register should be 0x41414141. However, it is not.
My Investigation
I tried lot of things, most part of the code is created by ChatGPT (due to desperate time consumption attempting to resolve it manually).
I tried compiling it with the following functions but no one worked:

gets (compilation issues)
strcpy
scanf (actual one)
strcmp

Also, I tried to write the code for a Windows environemnt to execute it with wine later, but I could not debug it because I could not disable DEP (Data Execution Protection) for this specific application.
At this point I could just conclude that this issue is being done by it's logic and no it's functions or executions...
Extra
Is there a way to hash the code and validate it hashing the input to validate them? I don't know if this one can be revealed by using forensic tools such ghidra...
Edits
Mon Oct 7 08:35:56 PM CEST 2024
I'm gonna add the result of the ESP register and the GDB output of the state of the app when payload is submitted.
I can see the payload but EIP is not modified.
GDB breakpoint output
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
EAX: 0x100 
EBX: 0x56558ff4 --> 0x3ef0 
ECX: 0xffffcd20 ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
EDX: 0x0 
ESI: 0xd8fe 
EDI: 0xf7ffcb60 --> 0x0 
EBP: 0xffffce68 --> 0xffffcec8 --> 0x0 
ESP: 0xffffcd20 ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
EIP: 0x565562ef (<handle_client+146>:   sub    esp,0x8)
EFLAGS: 0x282 (carry parity adjust zero SIGN trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x565562e4 <handle_client+135>:  push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x565562e7 <handle_client+138>:  call   0x56556100 <recv@plt>
   0x565562ec <handle_client+143>:  add    esp,0x10
=> 0x565562ef <handle_client+146>:  sub    esp,0x8
   0x565562f2 <handle_client+149>:  lea    eax,[ebp-0x148]
   0x565562f8 <handle_client+155>:  push   eax
   0x565562f9 <handle_client+156>:  lea    eax,[ebx-0x1f9a]
   0x565562ff <handle_client+162>:  push   eax
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0xffffcd20 ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
0004| 0xffffcd24 ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
0008| 0xffffcd28 ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
0012| 0xffffcd2c ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
0016| 0xffffcd30 ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
0020| 0xffffcd34 ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
0024| 0xffffcd38 ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
0028| 0xffffcd3c ('A' <repeats 200 times>...)
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value
0x565562ef in handle_client ()

ESP register output (Command: x/100x $esp)
0xffffcd20: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd28: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd30: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd38: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd40: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd48: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd50: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd58: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd60: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd68: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd70: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd78: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xffffcd80: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41

Mon Oct  7 10:11:21 PM CEST 2024
As dbush mentioned, the buffer could be after the email on the stack.
I made a quick check and it's true...
Compilation command
gcc -g -m32 -fno-stack-protector testlin.c -o server -z execstack
Memory location of variables
gdb-peda$ print &buffer
$1 = (char (*)[256]) 0xffffcd50
gdb-peda$ print &email
$2 = (char (*)[64]) 0xffffcd10

Stack view
gdb-peda$ x/100xb 0xffffcd10
0xffffcd10: 0x61    0x73    0x64    0x61    0x73    0x64    0x0a    0x35
0xffffcd18: 0x39    0x34    0x33    0x38    0x80    0xcd    0xff    0xff
0xffffcd20: 0x1b    0x71    0x55    0x56    0x2c    0xce    0xf8    0xf7
0xffffcd28: 0xb8    0xce    0xff    0xff    0xac    0x6c    0xdb    0xf7
0xffffcd30: 0x26    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0xffffcd38: 0xb8    0xce    0xff    0xff    0x80    0xcd    0xff    0xff
0xffffcd40: 0x1b    0x71    0x55    0x56    0x2c    0xce    0xf8    0xf7
0xffffcd48: 0xb8    0xce    0xff    0xff    0x42    0x1b    0xdc    0xf7
0xffffcd50: 0x62    0x70    0x68    0x79    0x73    0x75    0x75    0x78
0xffffcd58: 0x73    0x72    0x6e    0x6b    0x71    0x74    0x75    0x70
0xffffcd60: 0x66    0x77    0x63    0x79    0x0a    0x00    0x00    0x00
0xffffcd68: 0x64    0xce    0xff    0xff    0x98    0xcd    0xff    0xff
0xffffcd70: 0xe4    0xcf    0xff    0xf7


EIP is not overwritten until the handle_client function returns. At what point are you inspecting the registers with GDB? Make a dump of the stack (x/100x $esp) and see if you see the payload there.

There's a call to scanf right after the second call to recv.  Did you put that there for debugging?

@DarkAtom I edited the question post for a better view. I can see the payload loaded in the ESP register, but I cannot understand why EIP is not overwritten. I am also working on the code to make a return of the function handle_client, any update i'll edit the question

@dbush I forgot to remove it from the line haha, I searched that function a bit and I understood that this one loads a variable in the memory causing a buffer overflow if not well handled. Reviewing it now being "sober", it do not make so much sense... well, as I said in "My investigation" section, desperate attempts for this issue ':)

It could be that buffer comes after email on the stack, in which case 256 bytes (i.e. the max amount you read) isn't enough to reach the return address.

@dbush I edited the question post with the results, but your suggestion was true. I'll play with the code to check if that's the issue. Thank you :)

@dbush Okay, i'd like you to see my face right now... That was the issue... Changing the declaration of the variables buffer and email I can perform the buffer overflow and modify the EIP register. Thank you so much :D

I resolved the issue by swapping the declaration variables buffer and email. Also adding/deleting other stuff on the code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 6000
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256
#define CODE "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

int handle_client(int client_socket) {
    char email[64];
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    send(client_socket, "Ingrese el código: ", 19, 0);
    recv(client_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

    if (strncmp(buffer, CODE, strlen(CODE)) == 0) {
        send(client_socket, "Código correcto. Ingrese su correo: ", 36, 0);
        recv(client_socket, email, 256, 0);
        printf("Correo recibido: %s\n", email);
    } else {
        send(client_socket, "Código incorrecto.\n", 19, 0);
    }

    close(client_socket);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int server_socket, client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;

    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket < 0) {
        perror("Error al crear el socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error al enlazar el socket");
        close(server_socket);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(server_socket, 5) < 0) {
        perror("Error al escuchar en el socket");
        close(server_socket);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Servidor escuchando en el puerto %d\n", PORT);

    while (1) {
        addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
        client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addr_size);
        if (client_socket < 0) {
            perror("Error al aceptar la conexión");
            continue;
        }
        printf("Conexión recibida de %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
        handle_client(client_socket);
    }

    close(server_socket);
    return 0;
}


